# iOS calling public web service using token authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, asp.net-web-api

We're building a iOS application which integrates with a web service for data storage and retrieval.

Currently there are several endpoints which require no authentication, meaning there is no login from the app.

We're attempting to prevent non-app users calling the public web service using token authentication between the client and server.

The issue is that as there is no login required from the app, the token will be generated statically from within the app as there's no client submitted data we can use in the token generation.

This leads to the issue that anyone can decompile the app, find our public key and work out how to generate a token then call the web service at their free will.

Has anyone tackled a similar issue in the past? Are tokens the best way to prevent unwanted clients calling the service?

Or is there a way we can store the public key from within the app which protects it from people finding it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When User first start the app, it communicates with the server and send it your device id. The Server will use the device id to generate the Userid and key. You will use that to authenticate people after.

Comment: From what I've read, Objective C can not be obfuscated easily and is therefore easy to decompile or at least view the source code of. Some people suggest writing more in plain C or using third part services to make it more difficult but apparently it's almost impossible to do 100% - http://robnapier.net/blog/obfuscating-cocoa-389

Comment: Thanks for you call, I just notice that and I start to understand your problem more. I change my solution, will that work? Just like that post said. There is no way to stop reverse engineering. Just Ensure your 60% costumer have a good experience is the most important

Answer (score 0):

You will need to separate out the app and the credentials for sure. Here is one way you can do it. Say, a user installs your app. Next thing the user will need to do is to visit a web page in your web site to get an ID and a key. The web page can generate an ID and a key and show a QR code which the end user can scan to get the ID and the key into the app. The app stores the ID and the key somewhere and use some thing like [Hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk) scheme to sign requests, which the server can validate.

Comment: Thanks Badri. Unfortunately we don't want the user to have to visit a web page as described as this adds considerable complexity for people to start using the app.

Comment: Your app and the API absolutely need to share the credentials out of band some how. There is no other way. Whatever the app does and whatever the app has can be figured out.